# How to run a GitHub Action when a pull request is opened or the PR branch is updated?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub action that runs on `pull_request`. I would also like it to re-run when a PR branch is updated in order to verify that issues uncovered during review are actually fixed. I know I could use `push` but that would also trigger a lot of unnecessary runs since I only want it to run on pushes to branches that are part of an open PR.

Is this supported or do I just need to run it on `push` and ignore the superfluous (non-PR branch) runs?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it actually does run when you push to a PR branch, no need to add the `push` event. Not sure why my initial testing was showing otherwise. Carry on!